# Loop through sheets & delete all sheets not named after a month

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a colleague that sends out a workbook every day. everyday my colleague creates a new sheet for that day, at the end of the month, she creates a summary sheet named with the month's full name in ALL CAPS. my colleague has a habit of typing dates as 01.03.2024 "because she uses a numpad & the point button is easier to hit than'/'." - According to her. the daily sheets are named as such. I need to sum up some figures between date ranges on the monthly sheets. the daily sheets are irrelevant to me. of course, she types her dates on the day sheets the same way, & excel does not recognise them as dates, so I cannot do my formula. my formulas sum between month sheets.

I came up with VBA that fixes her dates & runs without a problem, except I wanted it to loop through all sheets named according to a month name & fix the issue on all those sheets as well. of course we are talking about (seeing as though this year is a leap year) 378 sheets by the end of the year that the VBA would have to loop through. so I decided to make 2 loops, the first loop would delete all sheets that are not named after a month & the second would then loop through all remaining sheets & sheets fix her dates. since I have added the sheet loop to the VBA, it refuses to run. If I click the run button, nothing happens at all. not even an error message. where am I going wrong?

```vb
Sub DateFix()
    Dim Months As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim VC As Variant
    Dim convertedDate As Variant
    Dim SheetC As Integer
        
    SheetC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

        Months = Array("JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "May", "June", _
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    
    For i = SheetC To 1 Step -1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Months, 0)) Then
    ws.Delete
    End If
    Next i
    
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

            For Each cell In ws.Range("A3:A50")
                VC = cell.Value

                If VC <> "Saturday" And VC <> "" And VC <> "Sunday" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    convertedDate = DateValue(Format(Replace(VC, ".", "/"), "DD/MM/YYYY"))
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                    If IsDate(convertedDate) Then
                        cell.Value = convertedDate
                    Else

                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What does setting a breakpoint on the first executable line of code and stepping through it tell you? Also, learning to properly indent your code makes it much easier to understand the flow of execution. You may want to fix that issue before you start trying to debug. And if your colleague types the month names in ALL CAPS, then why is half your array of month names in proper case instead of CAPS?

Comment: _"because she uses a numpad & the point button is easier to hit than'/'_  Maybe wait until she's not at her computer and pop that button out?  If it's not there she can't use it.

Comment: Your code doesn't pass the VBA compile. I don't think you can run it. You need to remove `End If` which is after `Next cell` first.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the assist. i was very perplexed with what I found from your suggestion. i did debug.print on thisworkbook.sheets.count the answer was 1, which is incorrect there are a lot of sheets. i then did debug.print on thisworkbook.name the answer was PERSONAL.XLSB why it would return my macro file, I have no idea, I then did debugprint on thisworkbook.activesheet.name the answer was sheet1 and I can confirm that sheet1 was definitely not the active sheet, i typed some nonsensical info on sheet 5 & got the same conclusion after rerun. I am now very confused about what is happening.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook ah yes, occam's razor.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you so much for your wisdom. I changed `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`, & now the debug.print answers are all correct & it runs as intended. Thanks again. Apologies for the bad indentation, I was pulling my hair out & had tried so many different things, that I stopped indenting.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a new workbook and ran it.

On the first run, I got a compile error "end if without block if" on the last 'end if' in your code:

```
   Next cell
        End If ' this end if threw the error
    Next ws
```

After removing that end if, the code worked as expected/explained. Although when it went to delete the sheet not named after a month in the array, it prompted message "Microsoft Excel will permanently delete this sheet. Do you want to continue?"

which can be solved by placing this at the beginning and end of your code:

```
Sub DateFix()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' rest of your code

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, for the assist. I removed the 'end if' & added the displayalerts false & true. the macro runs now, however now at line 'ws.Delete' i'm getting error code 1004 method 'Delete' of object '_worksheet' failed. I tried adding `For i = SheetC To 1 Step -1  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)  ws.Visible = True **********this line here*************  If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Months, 0)) Then  ws.Delete  End If  Next i` but that still didn't solve my problem. sorry for all the edits, I was trying to figure out how to write the code correctly in this comment. clearly I failed.

Comment: is it possible it's trying to delete all sheets in the book? Sorry, I am trying to reproduce your example, but it seems to be working as expected for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function arr_months() As Variant
    arr_months = Array("JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "May", "June", _
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
End Function
Sub OtherSheetsDelete(Optional Excluded_Sheet)
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction: Set wsf = WorksheetFunction
'....................................................................................................
    Dim Sht As Object
'....................................................................................................
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    If IsMissing(Excluded_Sheet) Then
        Excluded_Sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    End If
    
    Select Case IsArray(Excluded_Sheet)
    Case True
        For Each Sht In Worksheets
            On Error Resume Next
            If wsf.Match(Sht.Name, Excluded_Sheet, 0) = 0 Then
                If Err Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Sht.Delete
                Else
                End If
            End If
        Next Sht
    Case False
        For Each Sht In Worksheets
            Select Case Sht.Name
            Case Else
                If Sht.Name <> Excluded_Sheet Then
                    On Error Resume Next: Sht.Delete: If Err Then Err.Clear
                End If
            End Select
        Next Sht
    End Select
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
Sub DateFix()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim VC As Variant
    Dim convertedDate As Variant
'....................................................................................................
    Call OtherSheetsDelete(arr_months)
'....................................................................................................
    For Each ws In Sheets

        For Each cell In ws.Range("A3:A50")
        
            VC = cell.Value
            
            If VC <> "Saturday" And VC <> "" And VC <> "Sunday" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    convertedDate = DateValue(Format(Replace(VC, ".", "/"), "DD/MM/YYYY"))
                If Err Then Err.Clear
                
                If IsDate(convertedDate) Then
                    cell.Value = convertedDate
                End If
            End If
            
        Next cell
        
    Next ws
End Sub
```

On Error GoTo 0 turns off error trapping.

Use

If Err Then Err.Clear

Comment: This ran, however it deleted every sheet except the last sheet which was not named after a month. I appreciate the efforts though.